# Change all but the first occurrence of a column variable in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

In a dataframe, I have several observations for individuals with varying types of observations (`evid`). How can I change all but the first case of `evid==1` to 4? Here is an example of my current data and expected output.

Example data

```r
test <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), evid=c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0),obs=runif(16))
test
#>    id evid        obs
#> 1   1    1 0.01717950
#> 2   1    0 0.67278026
#> 3   1    0 0.77562908
#> 4   1    1 0.56772917
#> 5   1    0 0.15452241
#> 6   1    0 0.39563057
#> 7   1    1 0.57936260
#> 8   1    0 0.08393009
#> 9   2    1 0.33814922
#> 10  2    0 0.81755822
#> 11  2    0 0.41326641
#> 12  2    1 0.58086429
#> 13  2    0 0.88967230
#> 14  2    0 0.88536880
#> 15  2    1 0.95169172
#> 16  2    0 0.40508249
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Expected output

```r
test <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), evid=c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0),obs=runif(16))
test
#>    id evid        obs
#> 1   1    1 0.01717950
#> 2   1    0 0.67278026
#> 3   1    0 0.77562908
#> 4   1    4 0.56772917
#> 5   1    0 0.15452241
#> 6   1    0 0.39563057
#> 7   1    4 0.57936260
#> 8   1    0 0.08393009
#> 9   2    1 0.33814922
#> 10  2    0 0.81755822
#> 11  2    0 0.41326641
#> 12  2    4 0.58086429
#> 13  2    0 0.88967230
#> 14  2    0 0.88536880
#> 15  2    4 0.95169172
#> 16  2    0 0.40508249
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Any suggestions? I have considered using a for-loop with a counter for `evid==1` on each unique ID, but I'm not sure if that is the optimal solution.

Comment: Does the new group always start with evid=1 ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and a safe assumption to make

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all the great answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 'dplyr' and base ifelse():

```
test <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), evid=c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0),obs=runif(16))

library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(evid_new = ifelse(evid != 0 & row_number() > 1, 4, evid)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Returns:

> ```
>        id  evid     obs evid_new
>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
>   1     1     1 0.451          1
>   2     1     0 0.342          0
>   3     1     0 0.497          0
>   4     1     1 0.973          4
>   5     1     0 0.607          0
>   6     1     0 0.208          0
>   7     1     1 0.261          4
>   8     1     0 0.247          0
>   9     2     1 0.00894        1
>  10     2     0 0.491          0
>  11     2     0 0.484          0
>  12     2     1 0.0707         4
>  13     2     0 0.242          0
>  14     2     0 0.883          0
>  15     2     1 0.717          4
>  16     2     0 0.0343         0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

How about grouping by `id` and then using `row_number` to check if this is the "first" record for each id.

```
test %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    evid = case_when(
      row_number(id) == 1 ~ evid,
      evid == 1 ~ 4,
      TRUE ~ evid
    )
  )
```

Alternatively, you could use `cumsum`:

```
test %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    evid = if_else(cumsum(evid) != 1 & evid != 0, 4, evid)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if each group **always** starts with `evid=1`

```
 test$evid <-  unlist(lapply(split(test$evid,test$id),function(x) c(1,x[-1]*4)))
```

output:

```
   id evid        obs
1   1    1 0.51534838
2   1    0 0.01095015
3   1    0 0.88759361
4   1    4 0.89289062
5   1    0 0.57048684
6   1    0 0.29230884
7   1    4 0.03046934
8   1    0 0.23345930
9   2    1 0.41735515
10  2    0 0.06591433
11  2    0 0.36458230
12  2    4 0.87298100
13  2    0 0.22673513
14  2    0 0.49044623
15  2    4 0.93705170
16  2    0 0.22926336
```

Answer (score 0):

a `data.table`-approach...

```
library( data.table)
setDT(test)
test[, evid_new := evid ]
test[ test[ evid == 1, .I[2:.N], by = id]$V1, evid_new := 4 ][]

# id evid       obs evid_new
# 1:  1    1 0.6748111        1
# 2:  1    0 0.3838278        0
# 3:  1    0 0.9168156        0
# 4:  1    1 0.5016905        4
# 5:  1    0 0.5255054        0
# 6:  1    0 0.5267886        0
# 7:  1    1 0.0829317        4
# 8:  1    0 0.6037724        0
# 9:  2    1 0.3524584        1
#10:  2    0 0.8565646        0
#11:  2    0 0.2369810        0
#12:  2    1 0.6675597        4
#13:  2    0 0.1317532        0
#14:  2    0 0.9700450        0
#15:  2    1 0.7849832        4
#16:  2    0 0.6688295        0
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution:

```
within(test, evid <- ave(evid, id, FUN = function(x){x[-1][x[-1] == 1] <- 4 ; x}))

#    id evid        obs
# 1   1    1 0.75992404
# 2   1    0 0.99727569
# 3   1    0 0.77062084
# 4   1    4 0.29295958
# 5   1    0 0.55979218
# 6   1    0 0.32520676
# 7   1    4 0.77215695
# 8   1    0 0.79231459
# 9   2    1 0.42415506
# 10  2    0 0.80345629
# 11  2    0 0.21503195
# 12  2    4 0.49903807
# 13  2    0 0.85903611
# 14  2    0 0.68878068
# 15  2    4 0.07765666
# 16  2    0 0.18056603
```